# Query for students passed or not passed in specific Subjects

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access, database-design

I have a Table with Column Headings:

- ID Student_Name
- Roll_Number
- Subject1MarksObtained
- Subject1TotalMarks
- Subject2MarksObtained
- Subject2TotalMarks
- Subject3MarksObtained
- Subject3TotalMarks
- Subject4MarksObtained
- Subject4TotalMarks

I want to write a query to output the results for individual student who have pass at least three of the subjects.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then improve your knowledge on database normalization. Subject types need seperate table. Store subject type in one field, not have a column each.

Comment: What value determines a pass mark? @ComputerVersteher your feedback is not helpful, OP has a current schema and just wants some help, we are not here to judge, leave that for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ChrisSchaller, not judging but agree with ComputerVersteher - desired output would be much simpler with a normalized data structure. Current arrangement will likely require a VBA custom function. Poster has not shown any attempt to solve, there is no code provided for analysis.

Comment: Sorry guys, from a data purist point of view, sure I agree, but its a pretty simple and common problem... by telling OP to change the schema just for this issue, that is going to generate a lot of questions, otherwise they would have already done this. :)

Comment: On second thought, if there are no more than 4 subjects, a VBA custom function could be avoided. But what happens someday when you need to add a 5th or more subjects?

Comment: @ChrisSchaller that is not purist, just a basic pattern. I doubt, that OP was aware of that and maybe he will improve structure (if not he is at least aware for future)

Comment: Ther is no question in this post. Tag with just the DBMS you are using. Don't dump requirements. Show what parts you can do. Ask 1 specific question re the 1st place you are stuck. In code questions give a [mre]. See [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the data, lets make some assumptions:

1. A *pass* is awarded for a subject if the marks obtained for that subject are equal to or more than 50% of the total marks available for that subject.
2. The name of the table is called `Enrollment`

To return a list of students who have passed at least 3 subjects we can use a query similar to the following:

> This solution uses CASE to evaluate a 1 for a pass and a 0 for fail for each subject, then we sum those results and only return rows that have a score of 3 or more.

```
SELECT ID, Student_Name, Roll_Number
FROM Enrollment
WHERE 
  ( CASE WHEN (Subject1MarksObtained / Subject1TotalMarks) >= 0.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN (Subject2MarksObtained / Subject2TotalMarks) >= 0.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN (Subject3MarksObtained / Subject3TotalMarks) >= 0.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN (Subject4MarksObtained / Subject4TotalMarks) >= 0.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) >= 3
```

There are different way to approach this, but this query is simple to read and gets the job done.

If you are querying an access table, then `CASE WHEN` is not supported but you can use `IIF` or `SWITCH` to achieve the same results:

```
SELECT ID, Student_Name, Roll_Number
FROM Enrollment
WHERE 
  ( IIF( (Subject1MarksObtained / Subject1TotalMarks) >= 0.5, 1, 0)
  + IIF( (Subject2MarksObtained / Subject2TotalMarks) >= 0.5, 1, 0)
  + IIF( (Subject3MarksObtained / Subject3TotalMarks) >= 0.5, 1, 0)
  + IIF( (Subject4MarksObtained / Subject4TotalMarks) >= 0.5, 1, 0)
  ) >= 3
```

Comment: Access query object will not support this.

Comment: Is it access or MySQL? OP hasn't been clear, you can use the same logic in access anyway, its just slightly different syntax.

Comment: I presume Access is frontend because of tag and likely where they are building query. So in Access query: `IIf(Subject1MarksObtained>50,1,0) + IIf(Subject2MarksObtained>50,1,0) + IIf(Subject3MarksObtained>50,1,0) + IIf(Subject4MarksObtained>50,1,0)`. Apply filter criteria under this calculated field of `>=3`.

Comment: The question is not clear re DBMS. Unclear questions merit downvotes, close votes & comments, not answers.

Comment: Thanks you guys, all of yours are really a great help. @chris-schaller Solution worked for me. Although i had to make some changes to my table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Let's instead start by fixing your broken schema. A normalised design might look somewhat as follows:

```
Student
  ID 
  Student_Name
  Roll_Number

Results
 StudentID
 Subject
 Mark
```

Comment: Thank, Problem Solved...